# Way to separate two duplicates names in a single cell without a indicator?

Tags: excel, duplicates

I have a column that has cells where the name is duplicated in each cell. An example is John DoeJohn Doe is occurring in a single cell and this is the same for the rest of the cells in the column. I know a way to do it with and indicator such as a space or a comma but this one has no indicator I can think of because the names are smushed together. Please help with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `MID` and `LEN()/2`:

```
=MID(A1,1,LEN(A1)/2)
```

[image]

Comment: you know, I hate it when I am thinking this long complicated formula and you come in with this easy concise crap......grumble, grumble.  I will now slink back to my cave.

Comment: Eh. You got an upvote from me on your last `FILTER` answer.... the tables are reversed, I was overthinking it there.

Comment: it is funny on what one gets anchored.  That is why I like this site.  It keeps me in check.